# Why do I need `as any` in this overloaded function?

Tags: typescript

I have the following `hash` function that return a `string` when `encoding` argument is passed. Otherwise, it will return a `Buffer`,

```js
import { createHash, BinaryToTextEncoding } from "crypto";

const hash: {
  (data: string | Buffer): Buffer;
  (data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;

} = (data: string | Buffer, encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding) => {
  const hash = createHash("sha256");

  hash.update(data);

  if (encoding) {
    // Hash.digest(encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string (+1 overload)
    return hash.digest(encoding) as any;
  }

  // Hash.digest(): Buffer (+1 overload)
  return hash.digest();
};
```

the above function is working as expected,

```js
const hashed = hash("hello", "hex");  // const hashed: string

// or
const hashed = hash("hello");  // const hashed: Buffer
```

but, what is not clear to me is I have to define `as any` while the `hash.digest(encoding)` is returning a `string`,

```js
if (encoding) {
  // Hash.digest(encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string (+1 overload)
  return hash.digest(encoding) as any;
}
```

TypeScript will give an error without the above `as any`:

```js
Type '(data: string | Buffer, encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding) => string | Buffer' is not assignable to type '{ (data: string | Buffer): Buffer; (data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string; }'.
  Type 'string | Buffer' is not assignable to type 'Buffer'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Buffer'.ts(2322)
const hash: {
    (data: string | Buffer): Buffer;
    (data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: The problem is that you only overloaded the (type) declaration of `hash`, but not the implementation. The (arrow) function expression you are trying to assign to `hash` is not overloaded, and the assignment only works when it has an `any` return type.

Comment: Try using a normal `function` with multiple type declarations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with multiple call signatures is *never* properly type checked in TypeScript.  The standard way of writing an overload is with a [`function` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) like

```
function hash(data: string | Buffer): Buffer;
function hash(data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;
function hash(data: string | Buffer, encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding) {
    const hash = createHash("sha256");
    hash.update(data);
    if (encoding) {
        return hash.digest(encoding); // okay
    }
    return hash.digest(); // okay
};
```

in which you don't have to write a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like `as any`.  This compiles without error, but that's just because the compiler is only *loosely* checking the implementation against the call signatures. As long as you return something that looks like "a `string` or a `Buffer`" the compiler will accept it, even if it has nothing to do with the `encoding` parameter:

```
function badHash(data: string | Buffer): Buffer;
function badHash(data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;
function badHash(data: string | Buffer, encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding) {
    return data; // also okay, even though this is not safe
};
```

You can read about this at [microsoft/TypeScript#13235](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13235). It would be too complex for the compiler to analyze the function implementation multiple times to make sure each call signature is separately satisfied.  So for function statements it errs on the side of permissiveness, leading to un[soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness).

---

On the other hand, when you have a function *expression* like [an arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you have the opposite problem.  The compiler still doesn't analyze the implementation once per each call signature; instead it checks the implementation too *strictly*, only accepting it if the return type would work for *all* the call signatures.  For function expressions, it errs on the side of restrictiveness, leading to in[completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)).

So unless your function somehow returned both a `string` *and* a `Buffer` (e.g., the [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `string & Buffer`, it complains:

```
const hash: { // error! string | Buffer not assignable to Buffer
    (data: string | Buffer): Buffer;
    (data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;
} = (data: string | Buffer, encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding) => {
    const hash = createHash("sha256");
    hash.update(data);
    if (encoding) {
        return hash.digest(encoding);
    }
    return hash.digest();
};
```

You can read about *this* issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#47669](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47669). The suggestion there is for overloaded function expressions to be checked the same loose way as overloaded function statements.  But for now it's not part of the language and you need something like a type assertion, or some other type safety loosening.

If you assert that each value returned is the intersection `string & Buffer` then it will compile without error (even though it is essentially impossible for something to be both a `string` and a `Buffer`):

```
const hash: {
    (data: string | Buffer): Buffer;
    (data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;
} = (data: string | Buffer, encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding) => {
    const hash = createHash("sha256");
    hash.update(data);
    if (encoding) {
        return hash.digest(encoding) as (string & Buffer); // okay
    }
    return hash.digest() as (string & Buffer); // okay
};
```

Or you could use a single `as any` assertion, which, due to the "contagious" nature of [the intentionally unsafe `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), causes the whole return type to be `any`, which is compatible with everything, including both `string` and `Buffer`:

```
const hash: {
    (data: string | Buffer): Buffer;
    (data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;
} = (data: string | Buffer, encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding) => {
    const hash = createHash("sha256");
    hash.update(data);
    if (encoding) {
        return hash.digest(encoding);
    }
    return hash.digest() as any; // either return statement will do
};
```

Or you could just [annotate the return value](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) as being `any` without using an assertion (which is only accepted because `any` is unsafe and allowed to be assignable both to *and* from just about any other type):

```
const hash: {
    (data: string | Buffer): Buffer;
    (data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;
} = (data: string | Buffer, encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding): any => { // here
    const hash = createHash("sha256");
    hash.update(data);
    if (encoding) {
        return hash.digest(encoding);
    }
    return hash.digest()
};
```

Any of these approaches will "work" in the sense that the compiler stops complaining. But none of them are safe.  Indeed, using `any` makes it even easier for you to mess up the implementation without a hope of it being caught for you:

```
const hash: {
    (data: string | Buffer): Buffer;
    (data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;
} = (data: string | Buffer, encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding): any => {
    return 123; // also acceptable because of any
};
```

---

Again, overloaded function implementations are never really checked properly.  You can choose between false negatives, where the compiler fails to catch real errors, or false positives, where the compiler complains about errors that don't really exist... and fixing those false positives just means you open up the possibility for false negatives again.  So it's up to you which approach you take.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQCQwZwAsAaOAIWADsMoBPAFQnrQA8YBRS5CAEyoHM4AXzgAzKBBBwARKlpgYEaQG4AsACgN1EGnxgMyNHEIFCAeSjBBCDXDsoIlfPBNEATAC5EcAPQ+4aFASUKTOlpSCAD7kAK6iooFwwPhwlBDwBPhW1ABGADZGirHxgbb25QAUPFgYXmECcNFkcQlQAJRezSVQaurlldUwtXD1EY3FraRoXLwCnVQ0DEysHDN8ER0jMOH8veUiALxwVTV12w1NLYFTawIA-PPUdIzMbJzc6-xtcAcAfIhlfoOJwuUw-FDoLC4UwVaREDBuACsADZpG09kDjKYAHQxMCDNAnIbowH9YCiY7TD4Cb42PqY8roGAxKCULFEbF8fi6GAVKmzDYYoFCUmMtDM1nswicqw8iok+l2IS9EWadTaXT6QxwMwAN0CeQgGB4AGUhtgdJR4HTyqIYlwYMBHFKicNRlEJoFNl1WkKxPbkI7na5CK6zjtxj7rgFbhFHosXit3gKvuGBH67Q6nWyQ2GthHLt0btSIg9yAtnss3rGvgDFf1uCCpeDUJhsHgiLD4UjUQqGSHcfioa6+5jyZSa7TRZimSycziuXL+Z9R8Lp3ZZ5KB4vnPK-cqNKTM4Hs3AcsaO6HBm7zmNC61vVcekeA0G2eeeJe8+7I0-iyn40rV5VhLVN83TF8s2dD8v2vNM709EIY1AssKCeJZgOTFc6wZTc2WvZRfH8AAeABaUi4BgQhkiSFIDEMBQ0B4UkD3UVUtAwHQ9AMIwAEF8HwQIYAASStQJBJPZ0bXsRtnClLxpKBb9bw9KN2k6J8-QGU5wIQtT-0+QCMKTSd4N2FjwWUgtEIM+4jMTatQO+P4cMxWTQSIFtIXbGE4RMHs0S0+wBzxAkRyCuxxz5SdXIZDdxTnKUZW5XdlxpOACGOH8ADJENXfpVVwhKtwXWVd2+TKKhyvL9xVQ91U4zUeLgfjBNgXjKFoWLgTkkMFPXY44N01Sn0fboIsGnSf3vaM0rjct0IckCU02d190sobpps5CU1QitjMclafn+RSG0cXqwSOVsoS-PyERRQKBpCodsHCgaorm2tTqKiV5w5HdeU+-L9gGvCkoB+UMrozrCL8AJgCoxIwecKFLXgAB3YA8jyOAeAgFi6rVDVuO1Dq0nNNAOq6073Pk7rtKGMzf26MbfQGqyLm2z77KrZaVzM9ajg5vS-x2z49sW3msJpLwME647vDhwhAjQAbaZDLy22hTs7oC4HgpxULh2vfXIopaKnPpmdir+6UIaBibCut37wbK3k2gJjR2IaritSMABVfhCG69XTH6+sGZvay1NZwIJuFkaizFuYFoTKXTOGwXJsZ4bmcmZPSx5zCM7lrqXO++wwYARjcABmWH-AwPJ8AgDLkAYoZ8iMHI0GQDAYkEuAIApUvPbYoA)

Comment: I would think the nicer way to do the arrow function expression was to assert the type of the function, i.e. `const hash = (…) => { … } as { (data: …): Buffer; (data: …, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string };`

Answer (score 2):

Using overloading with a normal `function` declaration instead of arrow syntax allows you to accomplish what you're looking for. Bergi's messages in the comments help explain why. You're overloading the type of the variable that you assign the function to, not the function itself

```
import { createHash, BinaryToTextEncoding } from "crypto";

function hash(data: string | Buffer): Buffer;
function hash(data: string | Buffer, encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string;
function hash(data: string | Buffer, encoding?: BinaryToTextEncoding): string | Buffer {
  const hash = createHash("sha256");

  hash.update(data);

  if (encoding) {
    // Hash.digest(encoding: BinaryToTextEncoding): string (+1 overload)
    return hash.digest(encoding);
  }

  // Hash.digest(): Buffer (+1 overload)
  return hash.digest();
}

const hashed_1 = hash("hello", "hex"); // const hashed: string

// or
const hashed_2 = hash("hello"); // const hashed: Buffer
```

Comment: Yes, this also work except that ESLint will complaint _hash' is already defined. eslintno-redeclare_ on the second function signature and the function implementation.